# How do I prevent readarray from adding a newline to the array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I'd like to understand where that newline character `$'\n'` comes from and how I can prevent bash from appending it:

```
$ declare -a arr
$ str="readarray adds newline here:"
$ readarray -td ' ' arr <<<"$str"
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="readarray" [1]="adds" [2]="newline" [3]=$'here:\n')
```

I know how to remove it manually from the last array element. But I'd like to learn if and how I can suppress its addition which would be favored.

Comment: To split a string into space-delimited fields use `read` not `readarray/mapfile`: `read -r -a arr <<<"$str"`.  `<<<` adds a newline but it is treated as a field delimiter with the default value of `IFS` so it doesn't show up in `arr`.

Comment: Cross-site dupe from [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - [How to remove new line added by readarray when using a delimiter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519914)

Comment: @pjh: indeed, read -r -a works. Thanks

Comment: While I accepted read -ra as answer, it should be noted that this is not a perfect solution. One should be aware of an existing pitfalls that exists not only in Bash but in all shells: If there's an empty field at the end of the input line, it will be discarded, see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#IFS.3D.2C_read_-ra_fields_.3C.3C.3C_.22.24csv_line.22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `readarray` that's adding the newline; it's the here-string (`<<<`). Feed the string using a different method, like process substitution, and there's no newline:

```
$ readarray -td ' ' arr < <(printf '%s' "$str")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="readarray" [1]="adds" [2]="newline" [3]="here:")
```

To be clear, I'm answering the question about the newline, not claiming that this method is how you should go about populating the array. Using a single space as a separator is particularly fragile; even the wildly-unreliable `arr=($str)` does a better job of handling whitespace. But don't do that, either.

Given a whitespace-separated string, I agree with @EdMorton and the other commenters; `read -a` is probably the best mechanism to get it into an array.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. However, even if it's correct, the additional fork or sub-shell can be avoided by either using read or manually removing the newline which in my eyes are the better alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the usually desired behavior of a couple of commands that populate an array from some input:

1. `readarray -t lines < file` populates an array named `lines[]` with **all lines (newline-separated strings) from the whole input**, one line per array element.
2. `read -r -a fields` populates an array named `fields[]` with **all fields (spaces-separated strings) from one line of the input**, one field per array element.

For example (input courtesy of Rabbie Burns):

```
$ cat file
This truth fand honest Tam o' Shanter,
As he frae Ayr ae night did canter:
(Auld Ayr, wham ne'er a town surpasses,
For honest men and bonie lasses).
```

```
$ readarray -t lines < file
$ declare -p lines
declare -a lines=([0]="This truth fand honest Tam o' Shanter," [1]="As he frae Ayr ae night did canter:" [2]="(Auld Ayr, wham ne'er a town surpasses," [3]="For honest men and bonie lasses).")
```

```
$ read -r -a fields < file
$ declare -p fields
declare -a fields=([0]="This" [1]="truth" [2]="fand" [3]="honest" [4]="Tam" [5]="o'" [6]="Shanter,")
```

and here's a couple of options for splitting every input line into fields:

```
$ readarray -t lines < file
$ for line in "${lines[@]}"; do read -r -a fields <<<"$line"; declare -p fields; done
declare -a fields=([0]="This" [1]="truth" [2]="fand" [3]="honest" [4]="Tam" [5]="o'" [6]="Shanter,")
declare -a fields=([0]="As" [1]="he" [2]="frae" [3]="Ayr" [4]="ae" [5]="night" [6]="did" [7]="canter:")
declare -a fields=([0]="(Auld" [1]="Ayr," [2]="wham" [3]="ne'er" [4]="a" [5]="town" [6]="surpasses,")
declare -a fields=([0]="For" [1]="honest" [2]="men" [3]="and" [4]="bonie" [5]="lasses).")
```

```
$ while read -r -a fields; do declare -p fields; done < file
declare -a fields=([0]="This" [1]="truth" [2]="fand" [3]="honest" [4]="Tam" [5]="o'" [6]="Shanter,")
declare -a fields=([0]="As" [1]="he" [2]="frae" [3]="Ayr" [4]="ae" [5]="night" [6]="did" [7]="canter:")
declare -a fields=([0]="(Auld" [1]="Ayr," [2]="wham" [3]="ne'er" [4]="a" [5]="town" [6]="surpasses,")
declare -a fields=([0]="For" [1]="honest" [2]="men" [3]="and" [4]="bonie" [5]="lasses).")
```

or for splitting the whole input into fields:

```
$ readarray -t all_fields < <(tr -s '[[:space:]]' $'\n' < file)
$ declare -p all_fields
declare -a all_fields=([0]="This" [1]="truth" [2]="fand" [3]="honest" [4]="Tam" [5]="o'" [6]="Shanter," [7]="As" [8]="he" [9]="frae" [10]="Ayr" [11]="ae" [12]="night" [13]="did" [14]="canter:" [15]="(Auld" [16]="Ayr," [17]="wham" [18]="ne'er" [19]="a" [20]="town" [21]="surpasses," [22]="For" [23]="honest" [24]="men" [25]="and" [26]="bonie" [27]="lasses).")
```

```
$ read -r -a all_fields < <(tr -s '[[:space:]]' ' ' < file)
$ declare -p all_fields
declare -a all_fields=([0]="This" [1]="truth" [2]="fand" [3]="honest" [4]="Tam" [5]="o'" [6]="Shanter," [7]="As" [8]="he" [9]="frae" [10]="Ayr" [11]="ae" [12]="night" [13]="did" [14]="canter:" [15]="(Auld" [16]="Ayr," [17]="wham" [18]="ne'er" [19]="a" [20]="town" [21]="surpasses," [22]="For" [23]="honest" [24]="men" [25]="and" [26]="bonie" [27]="lasses).")
```

The newline in the array contents in your question is because by specifying `-d ' '` you told `readarray` to split the input at every blank char instead of at every newline. Newline is not a blank char so it's part of a field, just like every other char. The newline exists in the input because the here-string (`<<<"$str"`) appends it to the end of `$str` so that the result is a valid POSIX text "file" and so can be processed by all POSIX-compliant text-processing tools. Without a terminating newline the result is not a valid text file and so YMMV with what any tool does with it.

The crux of the problem is you're trying to use `readarray` with some options to do the job that `read` exists to do but there is no exact mapping between the 2 commands as they're for different purposes. Just use `read` instead:

```
$ declare -a arr
$ str="readarray adds newline here:"
$ read -r -a arr <<<"$str"
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="readarray" [1]="adds" [2]="newline" [3]="here:")
```

You COULD do `readarray -td ' ' arr < <(printf '%s' "$str")` to avoid the newline getting added but then you're counting on `readarray` doing what you want with input that isn't a valid POSIX text file, relying on there only being a single blank char between fields, and it's unnecessarily spawning a subshell to call `printf` which will be slow if you need to do this a lot.

Comment: Actually, "space-separated strings" is false. It should read "separated by the first character in IFS" as one can easily verify: `str="read,adds,no,newline,here:"; IFS=$',' read -r -a arr <<<"$str"; declare -p arr`

Comment: I said "Here's the usually desired behavior". There's obviously a lot more I could say about how various options and configuration settings affect both commands (`readarray` doesn't NEED to read newline separated input either, for example) but there's man pages for that.

Comment: The relevant information "The newline exists in the input because the here-string (<<<"$str") appends it to the end of $str" is buried/hidden in a lot of additional text. That's why I overlooked it in the first place and accepted the other answer. Of course, you're also right in pointing that out.

Comment: IMHO everything I included in the answer is relevant to explaining what the available tools are for splitting input into shell arrays and how/why each tool behaves the way it does given 1 line or multiple lines of input, before showing what you probably should (and should not) do instead for the specific case of 1 line of input stored in a variable but OK, hooefully others will find this useful in future.